# Magento how to save credit card details for Authorize.net

Tags: magento

I am using authorize.net payment gate in my magento website. I want to automatic reorder the orders which are previously receive.I have made schedule functionality in admin from which I can schedule the order but I wants to save the payment details of customer when he clicks on **Do you want to save card details for reorder this order?** in authorize.net payment section. or while he clicks on place order in order review section.
how can do that? I have tried following code in  OnepageController.php by overriding it in local:

```
<?php

require_once "Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php";

class Supplycity_Checkout_OnepageController extends Mage_Checkout_OnepageController
{
    public function savePaymentAction()
    {
        if ($this->_expireAjax()) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            if (!$this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
                $this->_ajaxRedirectResponse();
                return;
            }

            $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost('payment', array());
        if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {

     $customerData = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
      $data['customerid']= $customerData->getId();
      $dedata=json_decode(json_encode($data));
          if($data['isreorder']==2)
                {
          //Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setIsreorder("1");
            $connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')
            ->getConnection('core_write');
            $connection->beginTransaction();
            $fields = array();
            $fields['customerid']=$customerData->getId();
            $fields['cc_type']=$dedata->cc_type;
            $fields['cc_number']=base64_decode($dedata->cc_number);
            $fields['cc_exp_month']=$dedata->cc_exp_month;
            $fields['cc_exp_year']=$dedata->cc_exp_year;
            $fields['method']=$dedata->method;
                    $fields['cc_owner']=$dedata->cc_owner;
            $fields['cc_cid']=$dedata->cc_cid; 
            $connection->insert('reorder_payement', $fields);
            $connection->commit();
        }

        }

            $result = $this->getOnepage()->savePayment($data);
       //  print_r($data);die();
            // get section and redirect data
            $redirectUrl = $this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->getPayment()->getCheckoutRedirectUrl();
            if (empty($result['error']) && !$redirectUrl) {
                $this->loadLayout('checkout_onepage_review');
                $result['goto_section'] = 'review';
                $result['update_section'] = array(
                    'name' => 'review',
                    'html' => $this->_getReviewHtml()
                );
            }
            if ($redirectUrl) {
                $result['redirect'] = $redirectUrl;
            }


        } catch (Mage_Payment_Exception $e) {
            if ($e->getFields()) {
                $result['fields'] = $e->getFields();
            }
            $result['error'] = $e->getMessage();
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $result['error'] = $e->getMessage();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::logException($e);
            //$result['error'] = $this->__('Unable to set Payment Method.');
      $result['error'] = $e->getMessage();
        }
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
    }

}
```

I can save all data such as credit card month,year,method but unable to get credit card number please provide guidance how can I do it?

Comment: If your company is not for example "pci compliant" you can not save such data. This is forbidden by law.

Comment: Ok thank you but how can I get the "PCI Compliant" so I can take that details. And Also is there any another way to schedule orders which will place automatically after some interval

Comment: Well as for "PCI Compliant" it depends on your country.
As for schedule orders well you can use third party companies that can save this kind of that and after you will get token to perform some action on saved data.

Comment: Ok thanks can you suggest such type of tools which are compatible with  magento 1.8.1

Comment: Well you already have it http://www.authorize.net/ is keeping such data just play with their API (http://developer.authorize.net/api/) and that is it :)

Comment: Here you can find how to get transaction details http://developer.authorize.net/api/transaction_details/